# construct expression for label in plot

Tags: r, string, expression

I need to build some expression-based plot labels at runtime. The labels are either

```
df=data.frame(y=rnorm(100),z=rnorm(100))
hist(df$y,xlab=expression(foo[125*"%"])
hist(df$z,xlab=expression(foo[bar125*"%"])
```

or

```
hist(df$y,xlab=expression(foo[145*"%"])
hist(df$z,xlab=expression(foo[bar145*"%"])
```

depending on a logical condition which I test somewhere else in the code. I don't want to write both sets of `hist` commands and switch between them with an `if` statement, because in the actual code they're much more. Is it possible to build the expressions at runtime?

Comment: See `bquote` function.

Comment: Can't you save the expression into a variable during condition checking?

Comment: @Pascal, sounds like `bquote` will do the job. I'll dig into it.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, I should save a lot of expressions in different variables.  My example of course is quite reduced, but in real code I'd need to save something like `foo[125*"%"]`, `foo[bar125*"%"]`, `spam[ham125*"%"]`,`tic[toc125*"%"]`, etc. if `(condition==T)` or `foo[145*"%"]`, `foo[bar145*"%"]`, `spam[ham145*"%"]`,`tic[toc145*"%"]` if `(condition==F)`. It would be much better to have some code where only the number in the expression is a variable. And anyway, even if I try to define `var="spam[ham145*"%"]"`, R complains `Error: unexpected input in "var="spam[ham145*"%"]""`

Comment: Set up a small example and we can work from there.